# What does the gossip stone message about "crows that fly near the town walls" mean?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

When using the Mask of Truth, a gossip stone told me this:

> It seems the crows that fly near the town walls are fond of musical instruments …

I've tried playing my instrument as all races, but the crow just keeps on flying.

Does this text mean anything at all?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The crow is called a Guay.

> The solitary Guay that flies around Clock Town in Majora's Mask will
>   ignore Link until he plays one of the four Temple songs, at which
>   point it will begin dropping progressively more valuable Rupees.

You can read all about these guys here, although there isn't much: [Guay](http://zeldawiki.org/Guay)

Comment: Overall its a sad time... Only get ruppies, I've got ruppies coming out my ears :p I'm after the heat pieces... But I refuse to read a guide online! Of course Arcade Overflow doesn't count as online...

Comment: @JamieHutber It was a very good question to ask. I love questions on Arcade that deal with asking questions about sayings or secrets.

Comment: Especially when I've tried playing him songs :p Greedy crow. I hate tourtorials.. I'm currently on a Zelda tour in a bid to play every single game start to finished. Its taken me 1 year to get to Majors Mask... A whole lot of gaming right there :D On my tube journeys.

Comment: Currently finding all the fairies, also in this "game quest" I must complete all the games 100%... The gold skulcila's killed me.

Answer (score 3):

If you play one of the Temple songs (Sonata of Awakening, Goron Lullaby, New Wave Bossa Nova, Elegy of Emptiness), it will begin dropping Rupees.